# Create a Bazel archives tar for an airgapped environment

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I created a Bazel archive tar using the steps provides in the Bazel docs. Most of the packages are being loaded locally except for this one. Please see error below.

---

> C:\Developers\examples-master\java-tutorial>bazel build --distdir=C:\Developers\bazel-tar //:ProjectRunner Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it... INFO: Repository remotejdk11_win instantiated at: no stack (--record_rule_instantiation_callstack not enabled) Repository rule http_archive defined at: C:/users/syuopm/_bazel_syuopm/v5bxa2ms/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl:336:31: in WARNING: Download from https://mirror.bazel.build/openjdk/azul-zulu11.37.17-ca-jdk11.0.6/zulu11.37.17-ca-jdk11.0.6-win_x64.zip failed: class java.io.IOException connect timed out ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'remotejdk11_win': java.io.IOException: Error downloading [https://mirror.bazel.build/openjdk/azul-zulu11.37.17-ca-jdk11.0.6/zulu11.37.17-ca-jdk11.0.6-win_x64.zip] to C:/users/syuopm/_bazel_syuopm/v5bxa2ms/external/remotejdk11_win/zulu11.37.17-ca-jdk11.0.6-win_x64.zip: connect timed out INFO: Repository remote_java_tools_windows instantiated at: no stack (--record_rule_instantiation_callstack not enabled) Repository rule http_archive defined at: C:/users/syuopm/_bazel_syuopm/v5bxa2ms/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl:336:31: in ERROR: C:/users/syuopm/_bazel_syuopm/v5bxa2ms/external/bazel_tools/tools/jdk/BUILD:492:6: @bazel_tools//tools/jdk:remote_jdk11 depends on @remotejdk11_win//:jdk in repository @remotejdk11_win which failed to fetch. no such package '@remotejdk11_win//': java.io.IOException: Error downloading [https://mirror.bazel.build/openjdk/azul-zulu11.37.17-ca-jdk11.0.6/zulu11.37.17-ca-jdk11.0.6-win_x64.zip] to C:/users/syuopm/_bazel_syuopm/v5bxa2ms/external/remotejdk11_win/zulu11.37.17-ca-jdk11.0.6-win_x64.zip: connect timed out ERROR: Analysis of target '//:ProjectRunner' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed INFO: Elapsed time: 68.089s INFO: 0 processes. FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (16 packages loaded, 305 targets configured)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a network issue most likely due to some firewall or proxy server sitting between your computer and the Bazel repo. The following download failed:

> Download from https://mirror.bazel.build/openjdk/azul-zulu11.37.17-ca-jdk11.0.6/zulu11.37.17-ca-jdk11.0.6-win_x64.zip failed

I suggest you download the file manually and follow the guidance [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/6196#issuecomment-441193202):

> A work around is to fetch the files manually and put them in a directory specified via the `--distdir` option.

Answer (score 0):

Those are mirror artifacts which are updated by the bazel team [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/new?assignees=&labels=mirror%20request%2Ctype%3A%20process%2CP2%2Cteam-OSS&template=mirror_request.yml&title=%5BMirror%5D%20). I think the archive URL which you mentioned above is mirrored and updated with latest files. If you see such observations may be you can raise the issues in that specific templates.